# Internal Access to Coreference Resolution System (Stanford CoreNLP)

Tags: twitter, nlp, resolution, stanford-nlp

I am trying to accomplish coreference resolution within text in Tweets. I would like to use a system built for the Twitter use case as much as possible, so my plan is to do my tokenization and POS tagging using the ark-tweet-nlp package by CMU. I then would like to integrate this with the coreference resolution system in Stanford NLP (my plan is to use the Penn Treebank style tagger from CMU for easier integration).

I am new to Stanford NLP, and although I have been able to implement it's coreference resolution functionality, I can only figure out how to use it for the black box case of it handling all of it's POS, Lemma, NER, and Parsing through the properties interface. I have seen examples online of how to access the parser with outside POS, and tokens through a Java interface:

```
String[] sent3 = { "It", "can", "can", "it", "." };
// Parser gets second "can" wrong without help (parsing it as modal MD)
String[] tag3 = { "PRP", "MD", "VB", "PRP", "."           };                                                 
List<TaggedWord> sentence3 = new ArrayList<TaggedWord>();
for (int i = 0; i < sent3.length; i++) {
    sentence3.add(new TaggedWord(sent3[i], tag3[i]));
}

Tree parse = lp.parse(sentence3);
parse.pennPrint();
```

So I was wondering if anyone knew how to implement this case through a similar kind of interface for coreference.